Run local command before ssh'ing
I use VS Code on a cloud VM. My workflow is to:

Start the cloud VM from the terminal locally
Wait for the VM to be ready
Start VS Code
Connect to the cloud VM through the SSH extension of VS Code

Steps 1 and 2 are pretty straightforward but I wish I could make it part of step 4. Is there a way to ask VS Code to run a certain command or script before ssh'ing to the remote VM?
I've searched online but haven't come across any material on this topic. The nearest thing I've found was the postAttachCommand for containers in How to make VSCode run custom script when attaching to a running remote container but I want a preAttachCommand in SSH.
